# Ubuntu hanging almost constantly after changing NIC driver

Tags: drivers, freeze

## How I think it happened

I recently tried to install a different driver on my network adapter because I thought that my ethernet port was causing problems - turned out it was my router and that nothing was wrong with my computer.

## Symptoms

Now, my computer keeps hanging when I try to do anything, although System Monitor doesn't seem to register any kind of CPU usage. I'm not 100% sure that the network driver was the issue, but it was the last change I made.

Also, the "Wired network disconnected" message keeps popping up - but only in normal mode and when the computer is hanging.

Another strange thing is that if I start in safe graphics mode, the computer functions normally (most of the time). Also, the problem seems to be getting worse. The first couple of times it started hanging, I reset the machine and it was fine after that. Now I can barely get it to function normally.

It is also worth mentioning that the problem seems to have something to do with startup: if the computer isn't hanging after startup, it will be fine that entire session. If I restart, and it begins hanging, it will never stop.

Are there any possible options for "undoing" whatever it was I did? I would love to just be able to "Restore" to a previous configuration but I don't think that is possible. Is there any way to just uninstall all unnecessary drivers, in case that is causing some sort of conflict?

## Information

Ubuntu 12.04 - 32 bit

Intel Core i3

Integrated Intel graphics

### additional details

output of `lshw -class network` - notice that my ethernet card is not listed

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 88:25:2c:ae:c1:dc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.2.0-48-generic-pae firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d4500000-d4503fff
```

## dmesg output

My dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/kCPJfSdT - notice at the bottom it is filled with

```
r8101: eth0: link up
```

messages.

Comment: What do you mean by hanging, specifically?  Does the UI just become unresponsive?  
Can you get to a console `ctrl + [F1-F6]` and get us a `dmesg` output after it hangs?
Potentially install SSH and try and log in with your phone or another computer if that doesn't work (although since it's network related that likely won't work either)

Comment: Nothing is responsive when typing, moving the cursor or clicking. One moment the computer is fine, but if I try to click anywhere or type anything it will freeze up for another 10 seconds. I did get to the console by pressing `alt+ctrl+F1` but typing there was also very slow.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot `alt`.  That's great news that the console is still functioning, lets see what the dmesg output is once it happens again.

Comment: I'll get this as soon as it starts happening again. It's working fine right now, and I need to use the computer so I don't want to mess it up. :)

Comment: @Chris Started happening again today (I've been hibernating the computer, which keeps it in its "good" state). I posted the dmesg output like you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab a console (CTRL + ALT + F1) and enter the command: `top`

Now you can see which process is using all your resources.
(top shows different information than system monitor)
Look which process is using all your CPU and memory.

If *kworker* or *the driver*, then

- find ethernet driver with `lsmod`
- and then

  `sudo -s; echo "blacklist <name of the driver>" >>
      /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf reboot`

Otherwise try to kill the process.

---

Because your question was not entirely clear i made the following assumptions:

- You did not recompile your kernel with other options
- You do not suffer from a power management bug (but think about this one)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using rmmod on the r8101 module. Hopefully this has no unintended consequences, but for now it seemed to have stopped the hanging.

Comment: Actually I ended up blacklisting it like you mentioned because the module would get reloaded after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to restore you computer on Ubuntu, however, you have to have set it up first. You can check by opening the "System Settings" and selecting the "Backup" option. If you have and backup profiles you can select the option for restoring your system to one of them.

If you know where your drivers are, you can uninstall them by using the remove package command...

```
 apt-get remove package
```

or to remove the settings, which you will also need to do, run...

```
apt-get purge package
```

Of course; you'll have to re-install a driver after this.

I hope that helps you some!

Comment: Thanks, but I never did set this up.